# Website throws exceptions when database mirror is broken but principal is still alive

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring

In an emergency, when we had to remove a broken database mirror (Sql Server 2008) from one of our databases to rebuild it, our c# website started to occasionally (not with every database connection) throw an exception which said

**"database X is not configured for database mirroring"** in the *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginWithFailover* function call.

I can see why it would be unhappy about the missing mirror, but I'd like it to stop breaking my web requests - my end users should not be affected if the database mirror is down.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is by design, but it open happens if you are connected to the failover partner, and you then turn off mirroring.

"If you specify a failover partner but the failover partner server is not configured for database mirroring and the primary server (specified with the Server keyword) is not available, then the connection will fail."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Still, wish I could tell it not to throw.... its a big kink into the mirroring setup.